# Cut a specific part of a String

Tags: java, string, substring, handle, cut

First of all sry for my bad english...
I have a problem which I tried for hours now. Hope you guys can help me.

Situation:
We got a String with 24 numbers. I need to cut off the first 9 numbers and calculate it with modulo 97 and then I need to hang the result to the rest of the length. Finally I need to loop this situation.

Example output (pseudo):

```
Start: 123456780000123456131400
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Cut 9 of them: 123456780
Calculate: 123456780 % 97 = 30
The rest of the length: 000123456131400
Add result in front of the rest of the length: 30000123456131400
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Cut 9 of them: 300001234
Calculate: 300001234 % 97 = 22
The rest of the length: 56131400
Add result in front of the rest of the length: 2256131400
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Cut 9 of them: 225613140
Calculate: 225613140 % 97 = 64
The rest of the length: 0
Add result in front of the rest of the length: 640
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Calculate:  640 % 97 = 58
```

This is my code:

```
        String total = "123456780000123456131400";
        String ninecharacters = total.substring(0, 9);
        int newTotal = Integer.parseInt(ninecharacters);
        int newSum = 0;

        while(newTotal > 100) {

            if (total.length() > 9) 
                ninecharacters = total.substring(0, 9);
              else 
                ninecharacters = total.substring(0, total.length());


            newTotal = Integer.parseInt(ninecharacters);
            newSum = newTotal % 97;
            String summedUp = Integer.toString(newSum);
            String newString = summedUp + total.substring(total.indexOf(ninecharacters) + ninecharacters.length());
            total = newString;
            System.out.println(newSum);


        }
```

Output:

```
30
22
64
58
58
```

Everything is ok but why I am getting 2x the 58? How can I handle that?

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try it!

Comment: 4 Minutes of reading the 'How to Debug Small Programs' solved my problem sir! Thank you so much for your answer! I found the little bug in my code.

Comment: Cool -- the best outcome of all!

Comment: um.... what *was* the bug by the way?

Comment: Everything worked well the only problem was the output 'sysout'. I changed the position of the output and tadaa :) The next time I will go trough the steps to debug my code myself. Thank you so much again sir !

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm going to up-vote the question, but regardless, you probably want to delete it.